# Change ArrayList from an Object to more specific type

Tags: java, object, arraylist, file-handling, object-type

Is it possible to change the object type of an array list i.e. from an Object ArrayList to a specific object ArrayList. I have tried using a for each. Alternatively is there a way to change the filehandling method such that it can return a specific type depending on which file it reads from without duplicating code?

My Attempt:

```
ArrayList<Object> librarianList = FileHandling.getLibrarianRecords(fileName);
ArrayList<Librarian> libList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object addType: librarianList) {
libList.add(addType);
}
```

getLibrarianRecords code

```
public static ArrayList<Object> getLibrarianRecords(String filename){
                ArrayList<Object> fromFile = new ArrayList<>(); //Array of
                // existing librarians

                try{
                        FileInputStream fIS =
                                new FileInputStream(SYSTEM_PATH + filename);
                        ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
                        fromFile = (ArrayList<Object>)oIS.readObject();
                } catch (IOException ex){
                        System.out.println("Failed to read from file " + ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace(); //Catches an IO exception.
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
                        System.out.println("Error class not found" + ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace(); //Catches a class not found
                        // exception.
                }

                return fromFile; //Returns the array list.
        }
```

Comment: what does your file look like and how does the `Librarian` class look like?

Comment: Does this code works? Can you show the input and output?

Comment: Why don't you return a list of librarians from your read method in the first place?

Comment: The code does not work as it is not the correct object type. I get a cannot convert error. The file handling method works when I specify the object type. @Deadpool

Comment: I have 8 or so methods similar to it in which only the object type of the array list changes. Im trying to recycle the code without retyping. @daniu

Comment: have you tried casting `addType` as a `Librarian`

Comment: @user3170251 How would I do that?

Comment: `libList.add( (Librarian) addType );`

Comment: @user3170251 Thank you, this does work, and now I know what casting is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user3170251 for suggesting casting

```
ArrayList<Object> librarianList = FileHandling.getLibrarianRecords(fileName);
ArrayList<Librarian> libList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object addType: librarianList) {
libList.add((Librarian) addType);
}
```

For changing the type this does work.

Answer (score 1):

It is rarely a good idea to read objects from a file like this. That said all you really need to do is to cast the result of `oIS.readObject()` to an `ArrayList<Librarian>` instead of carrying it to `ArrayList<Object>` (as you do now) and then amend the return type of `getLibrarianRecords`. Oh, and naturally also the type of the local variable `fromFile`.

```
    public static ArrayList<Librarian> getLibrarianRecords(String filename){
            ArrayList<Librarian> fromFile = new ArrayList<>(); //Array of
            // existing librarians

            try{
                    FileInputStream fIS =
                            new FileInputStream(SYSTEM_PATH + filename);
                    ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
                    fromFile = (ArrayList<Librarian>)oIS.readObject();
            } catch (IOException ex){
                    System.out.println("Failed to read from file " + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace(); //Catches an IO exception.
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
                    System.out.println("Error class not found" + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace(); //Catches a class not found
                    // exception.
            }

            return fromFile; //Returns the array list.
    }
```

There should then be no need to loop over the list to actually do the type conversion on an element by element basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic class definition

```
class ArrayListConverter<T> {
  List<T> cast;
  public ArrayListConverter(List<T> typeList){
   cast = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Object addType: typeList) {
      cast.add((T)addType);
   }

  }
  public List<T> getList(){
     return cast;
  }

}
```

Just do this:

```
ArrayListConverter<Librarian> conv = new ArrayListConverter<>(libList);
ArrayList<Librarian> libListOg  = conv.getList();
```